# Cómo pasar lista de Java a C#

Tags: java, c#

tengo la siguiente lista en Java:

```
public List<? extends ModeloObj> getObjs();
```

Me gustaría poder pasar el código a C# pero desconozco cómo hacerlo. Mi problema se encuentra con `<? extends ModeloObj >` que desconozco como pasarlo a C#
La lista se encuentra `ModeloJuego` y `ModeloObj` es otra interfaz. Este es el diagrama de clases

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que intentaste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberias explicar si las interfaces heredan una de otra.

Pero en un ejemplo sencillo:
Creando una interface donde luego esta se hereda en una clase

```
public interface IMiInterface
{
  List<TuClaseOInterface> MiLista {get;set;}
}
public class MiClase : IMiInterface
{
   List<TuClaseOInterface> MiLista {get;set}

   public MiClase()
   {
     MiLista = new List<TuClaseOInterface>();
   }
}
```

Comment: Creo que no me he explicado correctamente. Tengo problemas con la keyword `<? extends>`, que por lo que sé no existe en C#. Desconozco la clase de los objetos de la lista, pero sé que todos heredarán de la interfaz ` ModeloObj `, he añadido el diagrama de clases UML por si ayuda

Comment: Si todos heredan de ModeloObj donde coloque <TuClaseoInterface> tenes que colocar List<ModeloObj>